# Load specific tab from URL Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap tabs and have some problems when submitting a form for example. It will always redirect to the index page and not to the page you came from. I'd like to use a link like index.php#LocationOfForm for example.

Linking to the tabs works fine from the navigation panel. I've tried a lot of suggested solutions, but none are working for me.

In the tabs I'm using AJAX to load the specific page where a form is located:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="LocationOfForm">
<div id="form"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").load("LocationOfForm.php");
    });
</script>  
</div>
```

And the script I'm using to select the tab:

```
$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
      $('#myTabs a[href="#index"]').tab('show')
      $('#myTabs a[href="#LocationOfForm"]').tab('show')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using location.hash and then :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if (location.hash) {
   // $element.click() on tab you want to be shown, bit dirty solution,
   // but works
 }
});
```

Then route back with `page.php#LocationOfForm`